# Derivation of HJB equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to derive the HJB equation in a stochastic setting. Let
me exemplify my problem with the simplest case where there is no control,
just one state variable. Assume the payoff is given by
$$
V(X_{t})\equiv E_{t}\left\{ \int_{t}^{\infty}e^{-\rho(s-t)}u(X_{s})ds\right\} 
$$
where $X_{t}$ is given by
$$
dX_{t}=\mu(X_{t})dt+\sigma(X_{t})dZ_{t}
$$
and $Z_{t}$ is the standard Brownian Motion. For any $dt>0$ we can
write:
$$
V(X_{t})=E_{t}\left\{ \int_{t}^{t+dt}e^{-\rho(s-t)}u(X_{s})ds+e^{-\rho dt}V(X_{t+dt})\right\} 
$$

$$
\left(1-e^{-\rho dt}\right)V(X_{t})=E_{t}\left\{ \int_{t}^{t+dt}e^{-\rho(s-t)}u(X_{s})ds+e^{-\rho dt}\left[V(X_{t+dt})-V(X_{t})\right]\right\} \tag{1}
$$

From Ito calculus we get that (and assuming that $W(\cdot)$ is well behaved):
$$
V(X_{t+dt})-V(X_{t})=\int_{t}^{t+dt}V'(X_{s})dX_{s}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{t}^{t+dt}V''(X_{s})d[X_{s}]=\int_{t}^{t+dt}V'(X_{s})dX_{s}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{t}^{t+dt}\sigma(X_{s})^2V''(X_{s})ds
$$
where the last equality follows from the known properties of the quadratic
variation of the process $X_{t}$. Plugging this back in (1):
$$
\left(1-e^{-\rho dt}\right)V(X_{t})=E_{t}\left\{ \int_{t}^{t+dt}e^{-\rho(s-t)}u(X_{s})ds+e^{-\rho dt}\left[\int_{t}^{t+dt}V'(X_{s})dX_{s}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{t}^{t+dt}\sigma(X_{t})^2V''(X_{s})ds\right]\right\} 
$$

Dividing both sides by $dt$ and taking the limit $dt\rightarrow0$:
$$
\rho V(X_{t})=E_{t}\left\{ u(X_{t})+\lim_{dt\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{t}^{t+dt}V'(X_{s})dX_{s}}{dt}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma(X_{t})^2V''(X_{t})\right\} 
$$
where I used the fact that when dealing with the Riemann integral:
$\lim_{dt\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{t}^{t+dt}f(x_{s})ds}{dt}=f(x_{t})$ (from standard
calculus).

As you can see, I am almost there. I just don't know how to deal with
term $\lim_{dt\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{t}^{t+dt}V'(X_{s})dX_{s}}{dt}$.
For example, assume $\mu(X_{t})=0$ and $\sigma(X_{t})=1$, so
that $X_{t}$ is simply the standard Brownian Motion $Z_{t}$. In
that case, to get the HJB formula right I would need:
$$
\lim_{dt\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{t}^{t+dt}V'(Z_{s})dZ_{s}}{dt}=0
$$
But I don't know how to prove that this is true. More generally (for
any $\mu(X_{t})$ and $\sigma(X_{t})$), I would need to prove:
$$
\lim_{dt\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{t}^{t+dt}V'(X_{s})dX_{s}}{dt}=\mu(X_{t})V'(X_{t})
$$
which I am also not sure how to do. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure to understand the point of the deriving the equation if there is no control, Also good notations help. Writing $W$ for you payoff is not a good choice. And your payoff is a function of time and state so $v(t,x)$ would be much better than $W(X_t)$. To answer your question simply replace $dX_t = \mu dt + \sigma dZ_t$, the expected value of the brownian part is $0$. PS: you forgot to square the volatility in the quadratic term.

Comment: I changed the notation. I also removed the dependence of the drift and variance on time, so that I don't need to make my value function depend on time.

In some economics applications it is useful to write the value function as a differential equation. Even if it is only to get some economic intuition from HJB.

Comment: You need only note that
\begin{align*}
E_{t}\bigg( \lim_{dt\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{t}^{t+dt}V'(X_{s})dX_{s}}{dt}\bigg) &= \lim_{dt\rightarrow0}E_{t}\bigg(\frac{\int_{t}^{t+dt}V'(X_{s})dX_{s}}{dt}\bigg)\\
&=\lim_{dt\rightarrow0}E_{t}\bigg(\frac{\int_{t}^{t+dt}V'(X_{s})u(X_{s})dt + \int_{t}^{t+dt}V'(X_{s})\sigma(X_{s})dZ_s}{dt}\bigg)\\
&= \lim_{dt\rightarrow0}E_{t}\bigg(\frac{\int_{t}^{t+dt}V'(X_{s})u(X_{s})dt }{dt}\bigg)\\
&=V'(X_{t})u(X_{t}),
\end{align*} as pointed out by AFK.

Answer (score 1):

By using the fact that the brownian integral has expected value $0$, we find
\begin{eqnarray*}
& & \left(1-e^{-\rho dt}\right)v(X_{t}) \\
&=& E_{t}\left\{ \int_{t}^{t+dt}e^{-\rho(s-t)}u(X_{s})ds+e^{-\rho dt}\left[\int_{t}^{t+dt}v'(X_{s})dX_{s}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{t}^{t+dt}\sigma(X_{s},s)^2 v''(X_{s})ds\right]\right\} \\
&= & E_{t}\left\{ \int_{t}^{t+dt}e^{-\rho(s-t)}u(X_{s}) +e^{-\rho dt}\left(v'(X_{s})\mu(s,X_s) +\frac{1}{2}\sigma(X_{s},s)^2 v''(X_{s})\right)ds\right\}
\end{eqnarray*}
So the PDE is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\rho v(x) &=& u(x) + \left(\mu(t,x) v'(x) +\frac{1}{2}\sigma(t,x)^2 v''(x)\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
or 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 (- \mathcal{A}_t + \rho) v(x) &=& u(x) 
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\mathcal{A}_t = \mu(t,x)\partial_x + \frac{1}{2}\sigma(t,x)^2 \partial_x^2$ is the generator of the diffusion.

Comment: You are saying that $E_t\{\int_t^{t+dt} v'(x_s)dZ_s\}=0$? I've just started to deal with continuous time stuff, but it is not obvious to to me why (I get that $E_t\{\int_t^{t+dt}dZ_s\}=0$ though).

Comment: You need integrability conditions on $v^{'}$. It must be adaptable and belong to ${{\cal L}^2}$ then you have an Ito integral whose expectation must be zero.